# Using divisibility rules to find digits of an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The problem is the following. Let a,b,c be a digit and a 7-digit integer 20ab13c is divisible by
792. Find a+b+c.

Comment: The place to start is [1] factor $(792)$ and [2] look for divisibility rules that pertain to each of the factors.  As an example, consider [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Opinions vary as to the appropriateness of your comment; many favor your comment.  Ask yourself two questions: [1] Did my comment violate protocol? and [2] Was my comment more helpful than your comment?